# What is a buffer in Computer Graphics

Tags: opengl, graphics, buffer

Give me a brief, clear definition of a Buffer in Computer Graphics, then a short description of a buffer.

Most of the definitions on the internet are answering "Frame Buffer" yet there are other types of buffers in computer graphics to be more specific in OpenGL.

Comment: A buffer is a block of memory, and is not specific to computer graphics.

Answer (score 3):

> Someone to give me a brief, clear definition of a Buffer in Computer Graphics

There isn't one. "Buffer" is a term that is overloaded and can mean different things in different contexts.

A "framebuffer" (one word) basically has no relation to many other kinds of "buffer". In OpenGL, a "framebuffer" is an object that has attached images to which you can render.

"Buffering" as a concept generally means using multiple, usually identically sized, regions of storage in order to prevent yourself from writing to a region while that region is being consumed by some other process. The default framebuffer in OpenGL may be double-buffered. This means that there is a front image and a back image. You render to the back image, then swap the images to render the next frame. When you swap them, the back image becomes the front image, which means that it is now visible. You then render to the old front image, now the back image, which is no longer visible. This prevents seeing incomplete rendering products, since you're never writing to the image that is visible.

You'll note that while a "framebuffer" may involve "buffering," the concept of "buffering" can be used with things that aren't "framebuffers". The two are orthogonal, unrelated.

The most broad definition of "buffer" might be "some memory that is used to store bulk data". But this would also include "textures", which in most APIs do not consider to be "buffers".

OpenGL (and Vulkan) as an API have a more strict definition. A "[buffer object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object)" is an area of contiguous, unformatted memory which can be read from or written to by various GPU processes. This is distinct from a "[texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture)" object, which has a specific format that is internal to the implementation. Because a texture's format is not known to you, you are not allowed to directly manipulate the bytes of a texture's storage. Any bytes you upload to it or read from it are done through an API that allows the implementation to play with them.

For buffer objects, you can load arbitrary bytes to a buffer object's storage without the API (directly) knowing what those bytes mean. You can even map the storage and access it like a regular pointer to CPU memory.

Answer (score 0):

"**Buffer**" you can simply think of it as a block of memory .
But you have to specify the context here because it means many things.

For Example In the OpenGL VBO concept. This means vertex buffer object which we use it to store vertices data in it . Like that we can do many things, we can store indices in a buffer, textures, etc.,

And For the **FrameBuffer** you mentioned, It is an entirely different topic. In OpenGL or Vulkan we can create custom framebuffers called frame buffer objects(FBO) apart from the default frame buffer. We can bind FBO and draw things onto it &  by adding texture as an attachment we can get whatever we draw on the FBO updated to that texture.

So Buffer has so many meanings here,